# NullpointerException when trying to fetch id from JSON subarray using sparsebooleanarray in retrofit api

Tags: android, json

I’m using retrofit api. Please check the screenshot below: I have category and sub category list in the dialog. On clicking “Ok” button, I have to fetch main category id, subcategory id , and sub category price. I used sparseBooleanArray. I’m able to fetch main_category id, but I get null pointer exception when try to fetch sub_category_id. Please help. [image]Attached code below:

MainAdapter:

```
 holder.select_category.setTag(position);
        holder.select_category.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        holder.select_category.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

        sublist = new ArrayList<>();
        sublist=chat_list.get(position).getSubCategory();
        subcategoryAdapter = new SubCategoryAdapter(context, sublist);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(subcategoryAdapter);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

        holder.category.setText(chat_list.get(position).getMainCategoryName());


    }
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

        }
    };
    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<chat_list.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(chat_list.get(i).getMainCategoryId());
                //mTempArry.add(sublist.get(i).getSubCategoryId());
                Log.e("MAINID",chat_list.get(i).getMainCategoryId());
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }
```

SubAdapter:

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.subcategory.setText(sublist.get(position).getSubCategoryName());
        Log.e("Sub Cat Name",sublist.get(position).getSubCategoryName());

        holder.subcat.setTag(position);
        holder.subcat.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        holder.subcat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
        cost_per_hr=holder.price.getText().toString();


    }

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    };
    public ArrayList<String> getSubCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<sublist.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                Log.e("TAG","INSIDE SUB");
                mTempArry.add(sublist.get(i).getSubCategoryId());
                mTempArry.add(cost_per_hr);
                Log.e("SUBID",sublist.get(i).getSubCategoryId()+"::"+cost_per_hr);
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sublist.size();
    }
```

Activity:

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                category.dismiss();

                ArrayList<String> selectedItems = categoryAdapter.getCheckedItems();
                try {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= selectedItems.size(); i++) {

                            Log.e("Main", selectedItems.get(i));

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ArrayList<String> selectedItems_one = subCategoryAdapter.getSubCheckedItems();
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= selectedItems_one.size(); i++) {

                        Log.e("Sub", selectedItems_one.size()+"");

                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

On clicking submit button, i get nullpointer exception for getSubcheckedItems() method.

Error:

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.app.qn.adapter.SubCategoryAdapter.getSubCheckedItems()' on a null object reference
        at com.app.qn.activity.EditProfileActivity$3.onClick(EditProfileActivity.java:303)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22651)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
2019-04-17 17:48:13.793 19440-21355/com.app.qn E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x774a444680 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x772d7e8a28 arg=0x0
2019-04-17 17:48:13.793 19440-21355/com.app.qn E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x774a444680 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Selvin: I know what is null pointer exception. My question is diffrent . please check my question carefully

Comment: `ArrayList<String> selectedItems_one = subCategoryAdapter.getSubCheckedItems();` , `subCategoryAdapter`  is null at this line I guess . add full activity and exception

Comment: @ManoharReddy: Please check the exception, I am unable to post full activity so posted only click event where array is called

Comment: If the line 303 on EditProfileActivity is  `ArrayList<String> selectedItems_one = subCategoryAdapter.getSubCheckedItems();` then it means `subCategoryAdapter` is not initialized , we cannot know if you initialized it properly or not with out the full activity code .

Comment: The question is *What is a NullPointerException, **and how do I fix it?*** so it is duplicate ... it should be easy ... 1. find out what is null 2. find out why 3. fix it ... point 2 need some java's basic knowladge - like variable scopes and some android's basics like component's lifecycle

Comment: @ManoharReddy Check SubAdapter class. I have initialized the array.  Does that make sense? But i haven't initialized in Activity. Correct me if am wrong please

Comment: @Selvin: Alright, if my question is silly to your knowledge downvote my question which you already did. Don't give unfriendly comments please

Comment: @Elackya sorry it might hurt you but selvin is right you have no idea what nullpointer exception is or atleast how to fix it .

Comment: @ManoharReddy: So i didn't initialize the array in activity. That's the problem?

Comment: @ManoharReddy has right ... without MCVE is hard to to guess what is `subCategoryAdapter` in given context ... *I have initialized the array. Does that make sense? But i haven't initialized in Activity. Correct me if am wrong please* ... you are right ... variable scopes (or .. if `MainAdapter` is inner non static class - you are wrong - and it is because timing is wrong(order of code execution)) ...

Comment: You didn't initialize `subCategoryAdapter` in activity that the problem . you initialized in MainAdapter . you cannot use it in activity

Comment: @Selvin,@Manohar: Thanks, I will check

Comment: When you are getting this exception? On clicking "Designer" or any other option ?

Comment: @Exigente05: I don't get exception on clicking checkboxes, I get when clicking ok button

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting null pointer exception exception when you have selected other option except "Designer"
It's because, from your screenshot i can see only designer option have sub category and you have initialized it based on having items.

For other options except "Designer" you don't have any sub category, and your sub category adapter is not being initialized.

This is causing `null pointer exception`

Your null pointer is saying your sub adapter is null.

To handle nullpointerexception firstly check your sub category adapter is null or not then do other operations.

**Surely, your `subCategoryAdapter` object is not being initialized at the time you are clicking submit button. Make sure your adapter initialization is within the scope.**